# What are Amazon Kindle Fire's screen density and size as far as the Android SDK is concerned?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

Can anyone tell me if the Kindle Fire's density is mdpi, hdpi, or xhdpi and whether its screen is large, or xlarge, as per http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Kindle Fire information can be found here : https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire

We are treating it as a large/mdpi screen just like the Nook Color.

Comment: 7" seems to be right on the border of large and xlarge, and I wasn't sure which one it should be. 169px from that FAQ indeed is mdpi. Thank you.

Comment: It is the same resolution as the Nook Color and it is declared 'large'

Comment: Setting up the emulator for these specs seems impossible - Android thinks it's xlarge. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895931/android-emulator-reports-600x1024-mdpi-as-xlarge

Comment: I manage Kindle Fire resources using -large-mdpi-1024x600 suffix for resource folders, but pay attention to devices with similar form factor and screen, like the Galaxy Tab 7" - http://rainbowbreeze.it/screen-density-del-kindle-fire-e-galaxy-tab (Italian post, sorry)

Comment: I use the suffix -large-hdpi-1024x600 for the Galaxy Tab 7' specifically because of their hacked screen density.

Comment: where should i store images for providing Amazon kindle fire compatibility?

Comment: I would use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() just like always, they have an internal sdcard mount point so compatibility shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Android reports `xlarge` size, even though it's 7" and 1024x600.

With this in mind, I had to short-circuit the built-in layout choosing mechanism, and choose the right layout in code, based on the device's logical pixel width (smaller dimension, to be precise). Late versions of Android support the same out of the box, but who'd want to lose backwards compatibility?

Comment: +1 i also noticed the same. Loading images from xhdpi only even though i have create drawable-sw600dp folders.

Comment: where should i store images for providing Amazon kindle fire compatibility?

Answer (score 0):

[**Kindle Fire: Screen Layout and Resolution**](https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/screen-layout.html)

- > **kindle fire 7" :**

  **layout-large-mdpi**
- > **kindle fire 7" HD :**

  **layout-large-hdpi**