# android kindle fire not showing application's graphics correctly

Tags: android, kindle, kindle-fire

I have developed an app running successfully on all the versions of android phones but it is not working, as desired, on Kindle Fire. I have configured the emulator as mentioned on https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire

When tested it on Kindle Fire, the graphics were not correctly positioned. Client want all the phones and kindle fire apps to have single apk.

Can anyone please tell me:-

1. Minimum sdk-version for kindle fire?

2. In which directory/folder should I place the graphics for kindle fire? (as I guess, kindle is picking up the wrong graphics.) Right now the graphics of kindle reside in the 'mdpi' folder.

Comment: `mdpi` is the correct folder, do you have a specific layout that isn't working right? Is it working fine in the emulator?

Comment: Me-an-Droid, I think you can find a useful answer from the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895931/android-emulator-reports-600x1024-mdpi-as-xlarge I have used the answer resolve my problem.

Comment: if u have any link for develop application for kindle fire, please give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the answer to your two questions go...

From your own link:

> To increase the probability that your app will be compatible with Kindle Fire, you should only use APIs that are backwards compatible with Gingerbread.

Also:

> Target: Android 2.3.4 - API Level 10

And:

> Abstracted LCD Density: 169

From the [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) doc.

> mdpi   Resources for medium-density (mdpi) screens (~160dpi). (This is the baseline 
>   density.)

Comment: I got it working by getting the device's height and width. The images were kept in mdpi folder.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some kind of similar problem when I tried to remove the fullscreen option within the manifest of our project: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`. Our app is also designed to be compatible with every screen resolution within a single universal apk.

Comment: Hi bbbreimmm, thanks for your time. I was able to get it done. App is running in all resolutions now. :)